# Problem with sequences and cofinite topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite Topological Space with Cofinite Topology.

Let $\lbrace x_{n}\rbrace\subseteq X$ be a sequence and let $a$, $b\in X$ be two points such that $x_{n}=a$ and $x_{n}=b$ for endless values of $n$.

Prove that $\lbrace x_{n}\rbrace$ does not converge.

Honestly, I don't know how to proceed. I though something about the fact that $X$ is not $T_{2}$, or I though to work on the definition of limit in Topological Spaces... but I don't know how to start. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Using all capitalized letters is considered shouting, and rude.  This may get your thread closed and maybe deleted.  Please do not do this again.

Comment: @Batominovski Agree! I changed the title. Beyond the fact that I don't like so much shouting, my glasses are good enough for me to see lower case letters.

Comment: Sorry, I swear i didn't noticed that...

Comment: A sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ if every open neighborhood of $x$ contains all but finitely many of the $x_n$. For the given sequence, "all but finitely many" necessarily means "all, no exceptions". Is this possible?

Comment: @Vercassivelanous I don't see why the condition for the converce in this case begin "All, no exceptions"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a \neq b$ and that $L$ is the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.

If $L \notin \{a,b\}$, $U = X \setminus \{a,b\}$ is an open subset of the cofinite topology that contains $L$ but cannot contain all but a finite number of $\{x_n\}$ knowing the hypothesis on the sequence.

And if $L \in \{a, b \}$, say $L=a$ for example, then $V = X \setminus\{b\}$ is an open subset that contains $L$ and cannot contain all but a finite number of $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: Why the open subset can only contains a finite number? I don't see it...

Comment: I'm not saying that the open subset can only contain a finite number. I'm saying that it cannot contain all the elements of the sequence except a finite number.

Comment: Ok, but why? We know only thet xn=a and xn=b for endless values of n, the open set is infinite so how I see that it only contain a finit number of the sequence?

Comment: Again, I'm not saying that it can only contain a finite number of elements of the sequence. I'm saying that it can't contain all of them except a finite number. That's totally different!

Comment: I think I know what you saying, but I'm not good with english. Anyway, I think you saying that, for example, there are some values of xn in U but U can't contain all the sequence. But I don't see the point because xn converges to L if for all open sets containing L exists \overline{n} in IN such that xn is in U for n > \overline{n}

Comment: But then by your hypothesis, it exists $m > \overline{n}$ such that $x_m = b$. And $x_m \notin U$.

Comment: The hypotesis only say that there are infinity values of n such that xn=b. Maybe it's simple but I don't see how this implies that exists this particular m>\overline{n}

Comment: By contradiction: $\{0, 1, \dots, \overline n\}$ is finite!

Comment: Now I see it! Thank you for the patience...